# PHP MySQL Storing a login history

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have an existing PHP MYSQL login system for a site. I want to record the history of every user login including failed attempts.

I want to capture the following data on the history:

1. username used
2. Time logged in
3. Date logged in
4. Successful - (answerable by yes or no)

How can I do this without changing my entire existing login system?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580534/best-way-to-limit-and-record-login-attempts and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357609/limiting-the-number-of-failed-login-attemps

Answer (score 6):

Create a new table with that info and insert when user logins ...

```
CREATE TABLE `login_info` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `username` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
    `success` ENUM( 'yes', 'no' ) NOT NULL
);
```

I didn't understand why you need time and date separately ...

Comment: I'd recommend indexing the `date` and `username` fields.

Comment: i think he meant logged in duration by "time logged in". like, user A was logged in for 4hours and 12 minutes starting at 2:11pm

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a basic understanding of OO code as well... Create a new table called login_info with fields as Mihai's answer then assuming your login method is a part of a user class - create a method that will insert a row into this table every time a login is attempted. For example :

```
class user {
    function login() {
        $this->login_attempt();
        // your login code
    }
    function login_attempt() {
        // insert into your login_info table
    }
}
```

This keeps your log separate from your login code.